# Is the output order of VALUES clause guaranteed to be the same as the order the elements are mentioned

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this statement guaranteed to always return the rows in the order that they are mentioned? In other words, will the elements in the VALUES clause always be evaluated in order from left to right?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS orderCol, id
FROM (VALUES (103), (7), (6), (16), (50), (41), (80), (67), (64)) x(id)
ORDER BY orderCol
```

Expected order:

```
103 
7 
6  
16  
50  
41  
80  
67  
64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's no such guarantee. SQL is a set-based language, where `{1,3}` and `{3,1}` are the same thing.

The only place you get guarantees on ordering is when you use an `ORDER BY` clause that unambiguously specifies an ordering of the values you're working with.

Since your `ORDER BY` depends on a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression that, in turn, uses an `ORDER BY` which is *completely* ambiguous, no ordering guarantees exist.

Comment: Just as i thought but could not find any documentation that mentioned it explicitly for the VALUES clause.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below as possible answer:

> There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using
> ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution
> unless the following conditions are true.
>
> 1. Values of the partitioned column are unique.
> 2. Values of the ORDER BY columns are unique.
> 3. Combinations of values of the partition column and ORDER BY columns are unique.
>    ROW_NUMBER() is nondeterministic. For more information,
>    see Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions.

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really really sure then maybe this is an option:

```
DECLARE @values TABLE
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        value INT
    )
INSERT INTO @values VALUES (103), (7), (6), (16), (50), (41), (80), (67), (64)


SELECT value FROM @values ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: There is no guarantee on the order of the identity values assigned here.

Comment: In fact, this answer very much begs the question since it *assumes* that the values clause *does* produce values in a deterministic order.

Comment: really? IDENTITY(1,1) means to me: start with value of 1 and increment by one for each new row!? it's a table variable so everytime you execute this batch the table identity reseeds

Comment: Yes, but who says that the first row that your `INSERT` places into the table will have the value `107` rather than, say, `50`? You've just told the `INSERT`, "please add these 9 rows to the table".

Comment: ok i see what you mean, so if you divide in 9 seperate insert statements it would be sure what order it gets. but looks awful to be honest

Comment: the problem i saw in the question was the ROW_NUMBER() clause in the statement - where i am not sure if this works correct on VALUES(..)